# Accessing glyph using \XeTeXGlyph disrupts content

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, fontspec

I wish to use KFGQPC Symbols font in my document. It's not a standard font as it consists of only symbols. It can be downloaded from [here](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/download/) named as `Symbols1_Ver02.otf`. The index of the symbols can be found [here](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/?page_id=486). I can access the symbols using

```
\XeTeXglyph <number>
```

However, using this command in the middle of other text, makes the text after it disappear.

Here's an MWE (considering the font is installed),

```
\documentclass[14pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgffor}% For loops
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\newfontfamily\QPCSymbols[
  Scale=2.2,
]{KFGQPC Arabic Symbols 01}

\begin{document}

First part of the sentence \QPCSymbols{\XeTeXglyph 32} second part of the sentence.

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \foreach \x in {2,3,...,97}{
      \item \QPCSymbols{\XeTeXglyph \x} \\[14pt]
    }
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\QPCSymbols` doesn't take an argument, it is a switch. So with

```
 \QPCSymbols{\XeTeXglyph 32}
```

you are actually activating your font for the rest of the document and as it hasn't much glyphs you don't see anything. Move the brace before the command to group the effect:

```
 {\QPCSymbols\XeTeXglyph 32}
```